# Writing a function to clean a python DataFrame using a DataFrame and Dictionary as input

Tags: python, function, dataframe, loops

Lets say I have a DataFrame where one of the columns is "category" and there are 3 categories:

1. cat_a with 100 records
2. cat_b with 5 records
3. cat_c with 1000 records

I want to write a function to clean that Dataframe. More specifically, I want to supply a dictionary with key, values to tell the function which categories to clean and how. Lets say I supply the function with this dictionary:

```
categorysize = {"cat_b": 0,
                "cat_c": 100}
```

My goal is:

1. I want to drop the "cat_b" completely that's why I set value=0
2. I want to random downsample the 'cat_c' from 1000 records to 100

I wrote this function but its not working. In all cases I only manage to drop one category or downsample the other. But not both :(

```
def df_reshaper(DF, categorysize):
    # I create a empty dataframe to write my data to                                                                                                                                               
    X = pd.DataFrame() 
    for key, value in categorysize.items():
        # If a key in "categorysize" has a value of 0 then drop that category from the data
        if value==0:
            DF = DF.loc[DF.category!=key, :]
            X = X.append(DF)
            return X
        # If a key in "categorysize" has a value > 0  then take a sample the size of value
        elif value>0:
            # First take a sample of x values for later
            DF2 = DF.loc[DF.category==key, : ].sample(value)
            # Then drop that category completely from the Dataframe
            DF3 = DF.loc[DF.category!=key]
            # Then add the sample from step x to the new dataframe
            DF4 = DF2.append(DF3)
            X = X.append(DF4)
            return X
    return X
```

The resulting DF should have 100 records for cat_a and 100 for cat_c

Answer (score 0):

The problem is how you use `return` as this will end the function immediately i.e. at the end of your `if` and `elif` conditions after only doing one of the actions your function will return immediately without going through the rest of the dictionary. You need to create an empty dataframe that you wish to return before iterating through the dictionary and appending columns to this dataframe which is returned at the end of your function outside of the loop.

Comment: Hi, I tried to place one single "return" at the end, outside of the loop, but it didn't work. Neither of the categories is cleaned that way. If I indent it, then only one is cleaned. The empty dataframe is created before the loop so that should be right!? And I'm appending rows to it in both cases of the loop, I think!? Thanks so far!